# MySQL/Phpmyadmin Impossible to set password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, debian

I was trying to install MySQL on my VPS which is on debian but when it tells me to set a password I can't do anything. I can just press "OK". It's the same thing when i'm trying for phpmyadmin.

[Screen of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vegly.png)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installation will not show you the characters you typed.

Just type the password and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: You are welcome :) will appreciate a vote-up on the answer (the arrow-up you have on the left).

Comment: I've installed php myadmin but when I go on : myserverip/phpmyadmin I have 404 Not found

Comment: This is a different question and not related to the original one, however the fact that you installed phpmyadmin doesn't mean that your server can run it using `http://ip/phpmyadmin`

Comment: So what should I do ?

Comment: I'm not sure how you installed it/which server you are using/etc. You might want to open a new question regarding this issue (but please provide there all the relevant information).

Comment: I've installed it with apt-get install command and i'm using debian 7 on a vps !